# Example of strictly increasing discontinuous function with intermediate property on non compact set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

I know that strictly increasing function with intermediate value property on compact set is continuous .I wanted to find counterexample if I remove compactness condition.Any help will be   appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is no such counterexample: the assumption that the domain is compact is unnecessary.  Indeed, suppose $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ is strictly increasing and has the intermediate value property.  Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$.  If $a$ is not in the image of $f$, then by the intermediate value property the entire image of $f$ is greater than $a$ or the entire image of $f$ is less than $a$.  Thus $f^{-1}(-\infty,a)$ is either empty or is all of $A$.  If $a$ is in the image of $f$, let $b\in A$ be such that $f(b)=a$.  We then have $f^{-1}(-\infty,a)=(-\infty,b)\cap A$ since $f$ is strictly increasing.

Thus in all cases, $f^{-1}(-\infty,a)$ is open in $A$.  Similarly, $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ is open in $A$ for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$.  Since intervals of this form generate the topology on $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that $f$ is continuous.